# Imagick PHP class for combining images to combined multi pages PDF

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

This is a very basic question about `Imagick`. Has it any php class for combining images to **combined multi pages PDF** like **Adobe Acrobat writer**?

I went through many similar questions like it in here but I haven't found any question about the exact topic.

I upload multiple files in different formats including PDF itself, combine these into a single long image and convert the files to PDF using imagick `appendImages`.

If I count on print media, it shall be a hassle for the users to select and print specific segment of content from such a long image.

I was unable to identify this topic specific resource about Imagic PHP classes. What is the best way to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

`appendImages` has no deal with this task as it combines several images into a long image in a single page.

To combine multiple pages or images into a multiple pages single PDF document like Adobe Acrobat writer the source file should be defined as an `Imagick object` like,

```
$im = new Imagick($files);
```

rather than an `empty Imagick object` like,

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im-> readimage($files);
```

I hope it helps the fellows in someday.